# Updated: How to span multile tables in Django for a backwards relationship

Tags: django, django-models

The Django documentation gives en example like so:

```
b = Blog.objects.get(id=1)
b.entry_set.all()
```

Which from what I understand results in 2 queries. What if I wanted to get the blog, the blog entries and all the comments associated with that entry in a number of queries that does not depend on the number of entries? Or do I have to drop down to SQL to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that Django at this point does not support this feature.

Answer (score 2):

```
Blog.objects.select_related(...).get(id=1)
```

Comment: I do not believe that works (http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/1e1fcee95759c370). select_related() does work for "forward" relationships, but not for "backward" ones. In this case Entries to Blogs is a "backward" relationship. Surely there is a way to do this efficiently.